# Changing Rails Model Association from one Model to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations

I'm having trouble associating a Project Model to an Organization Model through an organization_id. I started out with having the Project Model associated to a User Model, but then I changed my mind and decided to associate each Project created to the Organization that created it.

So, through Migrations I inserted a new column to insert an organization_id into the Project Model. The problem is that whenever I create a new project (logged in as an Organization), the organization_id remains "nil". What am I doing wrong that the association is not working?

This is the migration file:

```html
class AddOrganizationIdToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_column :projects, :organization_id, :integer, index: true
  end
end
```

You can check out the Project Model and the Organization model, with respective schema (through annotate gem) below.

Project Model (with schema)

```html
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: projects
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  name              :string
#  short_description :text
#  description       :text
#  image_url         :string
#  status            :string           default("pending")
#  goal              :decimal(8, 2)
#  expiration_date   :date
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#  organization_id   :integer
#  start_date        :date
#

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :organization

end
```

Organization Model (with schema)

```html
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: organizations
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  email                  :string           default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string           default(""), not null
#  reset_password_token   :string
#  reset_password_sent_at :datetime
#  remember_created_at    :datetime
#  sign_in_count          :integer          default(0), not null
#  current_sign_in_at     :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at        :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip     :string
#  last_sign_in_ip        :string
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
end
```

EDITED: Adding Projects Controller Create Action as requested:

```html
 def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You say organization_id is always nil. But how/where do you set it ?

Comment: How are you creating the Project models? Please show projects controller create action.

Comment: @SacWebDeveloper As requested, the Projects controller create action is up. Thanks!

Comment: @mmgrillo Well, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to set the `organization ID` on creation of the project, it won't automatically know on its own. Something like below should do it, this would be done in your `projects_controller.rb` file:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationsController
   def create
      current_organization = Organization.find() #the org id thats logged in
      Project.create(organization: current_organization)
      redirect_to #somewhere
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the organization's association methods to create the project, it will automatically add the organization_id. The following code assumes the organization ID you want is found on current_user.

```
def create
  organization = Organization.find(current_user.organization.id)
  @project = organization.project.build(project_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#detailed-association-reference